# Json and translation

Tags: json, gettext

I have a `json` document where *some* of the strings must be translated. For example (made-up syntax), my `data.json`:

```
{
  "greeting": "trans:Hello"
}
```

In this case the string `"Hello"` is marked as translatable with the prefix `trans:` (which does not seem very robust). I would then use a tool to generate a catalog:

```
xgettext data.json
```

And then translate the strings to my target languages. My application will then use my original json and the translations mapping:

```
translations = {
  "en" : {
    "Hello": "Hello"
  },
  "es" : {
    "Hello": "Hola"
  }
}
```

And would generate the final json (for target language `es`):

```
{
  "greeting": "Hola"
}
```

Is there any standard way of specifying translatable strings in json, so that they can be processed by standard tools to generate message catalogs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the appropriate gettext language preprocessor to extract strings which are marked, usually with `_(string)` or `gettext(string`), and create a gettext catalog (`POT` file) containing those strings. After you create a localized version of the catalog for a particular language, probably using a tool such as `poedit`, in this case you would then convert it into a JSON representation--for more information, and for ideas about standard ways to handle gettext-style message catalogs in JavaScript, take a look at [JED](https://slexaxton.github.io/Jed/)--and then load this JSON-formatted catalog into your app at run-time, and access it via utilities defined for that purpose.

The notation `_(string)` has two effects. First, it marks the string for the extractor. Second, at run-time it invokes a function called `_` to look up the string in the catalog and returns the localized value.

The problem with JSON is that obviously `_(string)` is invalid JSON syntax. If possible, consider changing this from a JSON file to a JS file containing an object.

Comment: It needs to be valid json. Does the gettest processor understand json?

Comment: I guess you are referring to `xgettext`, the string extractor. That would would understand JSON if you gave the language as JavaScript. The problem, as I explained, is that the `_("string")` format would not be valid inside a JSON file. Therefore, you'll need to work with JavaScript files containing JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the old question for references. One can generate from json a temporary JS source like `my_strings.js`

```
_("first-string-to-translate");    
_("second-string-to-translate");
...
_("last-string-to-translate");
```

Then pass this `my_strings.js` to xgettext.